# Sum of Distinct count in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following table:

**CUST_PRODUCT_DTL**

```
Cust_ID  Product_ID  QTY
1          10        5
2          10        2
3          10        5
1          11        5
2          12        1
```

How can I get Total Distinct CUST_ID, TOTAL DISTINCT PRODUCT_ID from the above table in Oracle 11 G

The below one doesn't work

```
SELECT SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT cust_id)), product_id 
FROM  CUST_PRODUCT_DTL 
WHERE  
GROUP BY product_id , cust_id
```

The desired result I am looking at is 
Total Unique Cust_id: 3
Total Unique Product_id:3

Comment: Please post the desired result with some explanation of your calculations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sum` is not involved, nor do you need the `group by`. Your desired output contains only one row. You just want two count distincts:

```
select  count(distinct cust_id) as total_distinct_cust_id,
        count(distinct product_id) as total_distinct_prod_id
from    cust_product_dtl
```